# How does Cryptsy's Trade Key system actually work

Tags: exchanges, development, cryptsy

I am building an altcoin to altcoin trading site wherein any Member can trade any altcoin for any other altcoin ... (Top 60 or so Altcoins are supported).

I need to know how Cryptsy's Trade Key system is written (internally) in order to use the method to enable my membership system.

I also need a GOOD crypto-related programmer for this and a related project.  Unfortunately, I have more questions than I can reasonably expect to ask here.

I am offgridsid and I live on gmail.

Comment: I get the impression that you are asking "How do I duplicate Cryptsy's business concept?" and "I would like to hire some talent." That seems to be a) awfully broad request for mostly inaccessible information, and b) offtopic. I feel that as it is your question is not a good fit here, and would like to propose that you clarify the scope of your question accordingly. Stackexchange includes a job market, so you may consider using that to post an advert.

Comment: Hi Murch,  Had no Idea about the job market ... it would be more appropriate but doesn't seem to be listed here.  Not so much Cryptsy's business model, only how a "Tradekey" system might be structured and implemented on a relatively simple crypto trade site. Having said that, I do need to hire some talent but really haven't had much luck with the traditonal "E-lance and Guru" approaches.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know how Cryptsy's Trade Key system is written (internally) in order to use the method to enable my membership system.

Most Bitcoin exchanges have a database that represents the balances of their customers. When a user wants to send money to another user, the balance is deducted from the account of the first user, and added to the second's. This is generally referred to as an [off chain transaction](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Off-Chain_Transactions).

Cryptsy chooses to identify the receiving account by a 40 character hexadecimal string rather than a username, which is somewhat unusual.

Comment: Thanks ... I  noticed that and thought that maybe the Hex string resolves to a wallet address or that they use it just to differentiate the Trade Keys from all the other wallets. I think I need a programmer to build an entire clone system since I haven't found anything "off the shelf" that would accomplish the same tasks. Any idea where I might find a good one ???